# React: Does order of assigning state versus binding functions matter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Does it matter if I assign the state attributes before I bind the functions?

Ex:

```
constructor(props)
{
  this.state = {
    attribute: myFunction,
  };

  this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
}
```

Versus this:

```
constructor(props)
{
  this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);

  this.state = {
    attribute: myFunction,
  };
}
```

The concern is that if myFunction() is being passed somewhere else and needs to be bound to use context-related variables like this.setState() then does the order matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. If you reference the function and *then* bind it, the referenced function will not be the bound one. Example:

```js
class X {
  method() {
    console.log('method', this === document.body, this === x);
  }
  constructor() {
    this.method = this.method.bind(this);
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
  }
}
const x = new X();
```

```html
click here
```

```js
class X {
  method() {
    console.log('method', this === document.body, this === x);
  }
  constructor() {
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
    this.method = this.method.bind(this);
  }
}
const x = new X();
```

```html
click here
```

Best to bind before referencing a method.

Another option, to avoid having to worry about it - use class fields and arrow functions instead.

```js
class X {
  method = () =>  {
    console.log('method', this === x);
  }
  constructor() {
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
  }
}
const x = new X();
```

```html
click here
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I needed. Quick question though, why does using arrow functions to define a class field work? Is it a property of class field to have an already-bound context?